# missing right parenthesis in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c

I have a problem with this code 
I check a lot this one but I can't understand why this error happend.

```
CREATE TABLE PP_EMPLOYEES_PARTITIONED 
(
ID_ONE NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
FNAME VARCHAR2(30),
LNAME VARCHAR2 (30),
HIRED DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
SEPERATED DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
JOB_COD NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
STORED_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (STORED_ID) 
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (21)
);
```

Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `DEFAULT` and `NOT NULL` clauses [the wrong way round](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6); instead of:

```
HIRED DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
SEPERATED DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
```

it should be

```
HIRED DATE DEFAULT '1970-01-01' NOT NULL,
SEPERATED DATE DEFAULT '9999-12-31' NOT NULL,
```

although you should not rely on implicit date conversion and NLS settings; either use `to_date()` or a date literal:

```
CREATE TABLE PP_EMPLOYEES_PARTITIONED 
(
  ID_ONE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  FNAME VARCHAR2(30),
  LNAME VARCHAR2(30),
  HIRED DATE DEFAULT DATE '1970-01-01' NOT NULL,
  SEPERATED DATE DEFAULT DATE '9999-12-31' NOT NULL,
  JOB_COD NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  STORED_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (STORED_ID) 
(
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (21)
);

Table PP_EMPLOYEES_PARTITIONED created.
```